# git push returns error 500 (Google Code)

Tags: git, google-code

I'm trying the following sequence of standard commands:

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/steambmc/
cd steambmc
[made changes]
git commit -a
[added commit message]
git push
```

I've set up my username/password in `.netrc`.

When I try these, the first two succeed, but the last one appears to fail:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://code.google.com/p/steambmc/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

I've also tried `git://` (which just hangs) and `http://` (which has the same error.)

`git` version is `1.8.3.4` on Ubuntu Precise.

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" its likely a temporary issue

Answer (score 4):

Edit .git\config, change the url from yourname@https://code.google.com/p/xyz/ to https://code.google.com/p/xyz/. When you push to it, just input your username and password, now it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your _netrc file or your authentication for the repo. I found if the auth isn't setup correctly Google seems to return 500.